# Fix UI hang when parsing large Uri on Flutter Web (without compute function)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue where I need to generate rather long URIs that follow the format of this code:

```
Uri _encodeDataUrl(String base64Data, String mimeType) =>
    Uri.parse('data:$mimeType;base64,$base64Data');
```

I am passing large(ish) amounts of data, so when I parse the Uri, the UI ends up hanging because of Dart's single-threaded model (see web performance panel). I can't use `compute` as it's not supported on Flutter Web.

[image: Performance debugging web]

I understand that web workers could be a solution, but I'm unsure how I would get my desired Uri class and the end of the day (end goal is to interface with package [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio))

Is there a way I could leverage web workers? Or any other way to prevent the UI from hanging while it processes this data?

Comment: please look at this package https://pub.dev/packages/isolated_worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a proper solution based on two ideas:

- base64 decoding must be done in a worker thread as it's responsible for blocking the UI when processing large payloads.
- Uri.parse() cannot be used with data Uri because under the hood, it stores data as text instead of decoded bytes.

The base64 part is handled in my previous post -- use [Squadron](https://pub.dev/packages/squadron) and decode the base64 payload in a dedicated Web worker or worker pool.

For the Uri part, the idea is to implement specialized Uri/UriData classes for handling binary data and make sure the decoded bytes remain readily available.

I've updated the sample code:

- specialized data Uri and UriData classes: https://github.com/d-markey/squadron_sample/blob/main/lib/src/binary-data-uri/binary_data_uri.dart
- Squadron service implementation to parse base64 data and build a specialized UriData with decoded bytes: https://github.com/d-markey/squadron_sample/blob/main/lib/src/binary-data-uri/base64_uri_data_decoder.dart
- Flutter widget to test decoding modes (sync / worker / worker pool) + circular progress indicator + timer ticks : https://github.com/d-markey/squadron_sample/blob/main/lib/src/binary-data-uri/binay_data_uri_page.dart

Here's the test code.

```dart
Future parse(String mode, String base64Data) async {
    if (_processing == null) {
      Squadron.debug('Start processing...');
      _processing = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {
        Squadron.debug('   parsing pending...');
        setState(() {/* refresh UI periodically */});
      });
      try {
        setState(() {/* initial refresh */});

        // make sure the proper service is initialized for the requested computation mode
        await _startDecoder(mode);

        final sw = Stopwatch()..start();
        final tasks = <Future<Uri>>[];
        var done = 0;

        Uri buildUri(BinaryUriData data) {
          done++;
          Squadron.debug('Result $done/${tasks.length} at ${sw.elapsed}');
          return BinaryDataUri(data);
        }

        // decode 5 uris of various sizes
        // if mode == _sync: data uris are computed one after the other and UI is blocked
        // if mode == _worker: data uris are computed one after the other and UI is not blocked
        // if mode == _pool: data uris are computed in parallel and UI is not blocked
        tasks.addAll([
          _base64UriDataDecoder!.decode(base64Data * 500).then(buildUri),
          _base64UriDataDecoder!.decode(base64Data * 800).then(buildUri),
          _base64UriDataDecoder!.decode(base64Data * 300).then(buildUri),
          _base64UriDataDecoder!.decode(base64Data * 700).then(buildUri),
          _base64UriDataDecoder!.decode(base64Data * 500).then(buildUri),
        ]);

        final results = await Future.wait(tasks);

        Squadron.debug('Processing done ($mode)');
        Squadron.debug('Decoded ${results.length} items in ${sw.elapsed}');
      } catch (ex) {
        Squadron.debug('Error = $ex');
      } finally {
        _processing?.cancel();
        _processing = null;
        setState(() {/* final refresh */});
      }
    } else {
      Squadron.debug('Already busy processing');
    }
  }
```

In "sync" mode, the output shows the timer never got a chance to run, and the UI is blocked:

```
[FlutterDemo] Start processing (sync)...
[FlutterDemo] Start decoding 20932000 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Done, res = 15699000 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Start decoding 33491200 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Done, res = 25118400 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Start decoding 12559200 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Done, res = 9419400 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Start decoding 29304800 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Done, res = 21978600 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Start decoding 20932000 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Done, res = 15699000 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Result 1/5 at 0:00:12.588199
[FlutterDemo] Result 2/5 at 0:00:12.588599
[FlutterDemo] Result 3/5 at 0:00:12.588899
[FlutterDemo] Result 4/5 at 0:00:12.589199
[FlutterDemo] Result 5/5 at 0:00:12.589599
[FlutterDemo] Processing done (sync)
[FlutterDemo] Decoded 5 items in 0:00:12.590699
```

In "worker" mode, data URIs are decoded and built one after the other, the timer executes properly and the UI is not blocked.

In "pool" mode, data URIs are decoded and built in parallel and the timer and UI get updated properly:

```
[FlutterDemo] Start processing (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo.11] Start decoding 20932000 bytes
[FlutterDemo.8] Start decoding 33491200 bytes
[FlutterDemo.10] Start decoding 12559200 bytes
[FlutterDemo.9] Start decoding 29304800 bytes
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo.10] Done, res = 9419400 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Result 1/5 at 0:00:00.283600
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo.10] Start decoding 20932000 bytes
[FlutterDemo.11] Done, res = 15699000 bytes
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo] Result 2/5 at 0:00:00.368700
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo.9] Done, res = 21978600 bytes
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo] Result 3/5 at 0:00:00.530000
[FlutterDemo.8] Done, res = 25118400 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Result 4/5 at 0:00:00.568700
[FlutterDemo]    parsing pending (worker pool)...
[FlutterDemo.10] Done, res = 15699000 bytes
[FlutterDemo] Result 5/5 at 0:00:00.597500
[FlutterDemo] Processing done (worker pool)
[FlutterDemo] Decoded 5 items in 0:00:00.598300
```

The Uri instances built with this implementation should be accepted by package `just_audio` -- maybe a bit of tuning might be necessary eg. if just_audio relies on the Uri's text content, I guess the String representation should also be held in memory along with the decoded bytes to avoid further encoding/decoding...

Comment: ty for your response. However, I am not able to get it to work. I do have a thread safe way already concocted using isolated worker, so decoding the base64 has not been an issue. This is my code that I tried (non-multi for testing)                                                                                        output[index] = ProgressiveAudioSource(BinaryDataUri(BinaryUriData(base64Decode(base64Bytes), mimeType: "audio/mp3")));                                                                         with no success. JustAudio responds with: (4) Failed to load URL

Comment: is it possible that because the code just uses the decoded bytes and does not include the format like this: "data:$mimeType;base64,$base64Data')" as its data that it's causing JustAudio to fail?

Comment: `BinaryDataUri` was missing a proper implementation of `toString()`. I fixed my sample. But this hinted me at trying with a specialized `AudioDataUri` which does not even try to parse the base64 payload. It simply builds the data URI once and for all and returns it from `toString()`. I've tested with just_audio and it just works, at least on the Web, not sure for other platforms. See https://github.com/d-markey/squadron_sample/blob/main/lib/src/binary-data-uri/audio_data_uri.dart. You dont even need Squadron nor isolated_worker!

Answer (score 0):

To keep your Web UI responsive while running a CPU-bound workload, you have no choice other than have your workload run in a Web worker to release your UI thread.

In your case, CPU is busy decoding the base 64 data. I've tried decoding the base 64 data in a dedicated Web Worker using Squadron (code available here https://github.com/d-markey/squadron_sample/tree/main/lib/src/data-uri). Unfortunately it won't help because Dart re-encodes data when constructing a DataUri with decoded bytes.

I was wondering: what are you doing with the Uri after it's decoded? Maybe there's another way using the decoded bytes directly (which can be done in a Web Worker leveraging Squadron).

EDIT (in reply to "end goal is to interface with package just_audio"):

I suppose you're using player.setUrl() or AudioSource.uri() which requires you build a Uri first. In your case, it's a data Uri so it seems inefficient because Dart's implementation works with strings internally.

I suggest you look at [player.setAudioSource()](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#working-with-stream-audio-sources) instead, and pass bytes directly to the audio player.

If your audio track is base64 encoded, you can use a package like Squadron to decode the base64 payload via a dedicated thread (Web worker, it will help avoid UI jank -- see my sample code). You can even stream data from Squadron back to the player so you don't have to decode the full payload in one go, and provide chunks instead (if you can tune chunk sizes properly, you could probably start playing audio before the whole track is decoded).

If your audio data is readily available as bytes, you won't even need a Web worker...